# Preventing recall in Outlook (2010)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there a way to avoid auto-accepting recall requests on messages you have received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article describing how message recall works](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/how-message-recall-works-HA001091760.aspx), you can do this with two steps:

First, in Tracking Options, disable "Process requests and responses on arrival". This prevents the recall from taking place until you actually open the recall request. Moreover, if you have already read the original message before you read the recall message, the recall will fail.

Then, via a rule, move recall requests to a new folder upon arrival. Recall requests will fail if the recall message is not in the same folder as the original message, so this prevents it from happening automatically.

Comment: Here's the missing trick, though: [advice about how to build a rule that matches recall requests here].

Comment: I did this myself by creating a rule that matches "Recall:" in the subject line or the words "would like to recall" in the body.  Not ideal, but tested to work successfully.

Answer (score 3):

To enable/disable:

Tools
Options
Preferences -> Email Options
Tracking Options
Uncheck "Process requests and responses on arrival
Uncheck "Process receipts on arrival"